# Understanding embedded points of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme finite type over a field. The embedded points of $X$ are defined as the embedded points of $\mathcal{O}_X$ as $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.

I'm wondering that is there a more geometric way to understand embedded points? For example, what are embedded points look like when $\dim X=1$?

If $X$ has no embedded point, then one can show that every irreducible component of $X$ is one-dimensional. I'm wondering if the converse holds, i.e. if every irreducible component of $X$ has dimension one, then $X$ has no embedded point?

Comment: The disjoint union $\mathbb A^1 \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} k = \operatorname{Spec}( k[x] \times k)$ is $1$-dimensional, does not have embedded points, but has irreducible components of different dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embedded points care about things that are more scheme-theoretic in nature - for instance, $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy,y^2)$ has an embedded point $(x,y)$ but the underlying topological space is the same as $\Bbb A^1$. So this already shows that your final question has a negative answer.

For a generically reduced 1-dimensional scheme of finite type over a field, embedded points are precisely the non-reduced closed points. Omitting the generically reduced assumption, things get more complicated, but in general, one should think of embedded points as generic points of subvarieties that have more nilpotents than their surroundings.

Comment: It seems to me that the embedded point is $(x,y)$ and not $(y)$ because the point $(y)$ is the generic point and $(x,y)$ is an associated point that is a specialization of $(y)$ (the embedded point being the associated points that are not generic ie that are specialization of some other point).

Comment: @GabrielSoranzo thanks for pointing out the typo, it's been fixed.